# Symfony check if user is authenticated

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony project I'm using `UserInterface` in my `User` entity to handle authentication. I also use `EquatableInterface` to check if user's email is changed while he's logged in.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof Account) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->email !== $user->getEmail()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

All works as expected, but when I change user's email in DB I'm not logged out, just not authenticated as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: https://s15.postimg.org/6md5htszf/22781921b8.png]

So I would know how can I check in a controller if user is authenticated? And how can I force user to log out when `isEqualTo` returns false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution and I want to share it if someone else have the same problem.

To check if user is authenticated, we need [TokenInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html) which is implemented by [TokenStorage](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorage.html). Then we just need to call [isAuthenticated()](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html#method_isAuthenticated) method.

```
$tokenInterface = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
$isAuthenticated = $tokenInterface->isAuthenticated()
```

[Since Symfony 5.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/42650) this method is deprecated (and removed in 6), so in that case you have to check if `getUser()` returns `null` to do the same check.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Method: see method `getUser` in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` at [link](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L373-L389). If you need this behavior somewhere in the service, then use the `security.token_storage` service as a dependency.

Try way method (symfony-like): you need use Symfony Security [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)